# Recording from VCV Rack using Logic Pro X

Tags: recording, logic-pro

I'm using VCV rack on MacOS High Sierra to create some synth patches and I want to record them. From a quick Google search, I found that Soundflower is a way to record the sound output from one program to another.

I downloaded it and I used it as the output on VCV rack

[image]

Then, on Logic Pro X I've assigned soundflower as the input

[image]

(It automatically assigned it as the output as well). I get no sound from either of the programs, but there is a signal on the Audio channel:

[image]

But when I hit record, the sound isn't recorded (even when the audio channel is armed)

Why can't I record this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If any of you guys know some other way to record this (another program or something), I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Not sure I should do a software rec as an answer... but I dumped Soundflower years ago when it got really flaky. These days I tend to use Rogue Amoeba stuff, [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) or in this case, [Loopback](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) might be best. Not cheap for one-trick ponies, but they 'just work'.

Comment: Check this out (uses in-built IAC Driver) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTrkYAOfVSQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of VCV Rack 0.6.2c the only legit way to record VCV out in Logic Pro X (or any other DAW) is using [VCV Bridge Plugin](https://vcvrack.com/manual/Bridge.html)

> VCV Bridge allows audio, MIDI, DAW transport, and DAW clocks to be transferred between Rack and your DAW through the included VST/AU instrument/effect Bridge plugins.

You can check out this YT video - [Logic Pro X with VCV Rack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTrkYAOfVSQ)

Though, you need to understand that VCV Rack is still in beta version (hence 0.x.x) and Bridge is just a makeshift solution. As [this article](http://cdm.link/2019/02/vcv-rack-1-0/) points out

> VCV Bridge is already deprecated, and will be removed from Rack 2.0. Bridge was effectively a stopgap for allowing crude audio and MIDI integration with DAWs.

also from the same article

> A DAW plug-in will be launched as a paid add-on, with support for “multiple instances, DAW automation with parameter labels, offline rendering, MIDI input, DAW transport, and multi-channel audio.”

Now if you want to independently record the Rack output, the best bet is using Rack modules available via [Rack’s plug-in manager](https://vcvrack.com/plugins.html) - The free [NYSTHI modules for VCV Rack](https://github.com/nysthi/nysthi/blob/master/README.md) is a multitrack recorder module.

[image: src - cdm.link]

The advantage of using a module for recording is that you don't have to resolve the audio-routing dependencies that come into play when an external piece of software is used and it is less resource intensive.

Though, I'm eagerly awaiting the release of the official plugin, that will sky-rocket the capability of this amazing piece o software!

---

An update (December 2019) : [Record VCV Rack output in any DAW in MacOS](https://medium.com/@lyricroy/record-vcv-rack-output-in-any-daw-in-macos-b6f69f0a0e4e)

Answer (score 0):

I used to use SoundFlower, IIRC setting that as the output specifically means that there won't be any output from your speakers (i.e., you shouldn't hear anything). I'm not well-versed with Logic Pro X, however I can say that an alternative to using the in-app record would be to do an auto recording with Quicktime with the input being soundflower.

Comment: Yeah, I found out that you can record it from Quicktime. How's the quality though?